# call/receive data from javascript from an android activity without web view

Tags: javascript, android, json, android-activity, android-actionbar

I created a small application using android studio. When i click a button, which is found in the action bar, I need to first call a javascript method and afterwards get the json data from that javascript method, and show the data in the activity.

I am aware that this can be done by using a web view but if possible, i need to create this without using web view.

hope someone can help me because i'm really stuck here

thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure how you could implement this since you need a javascript engine. And only the `WebView` has such a feature.